# A digital certificate contain only one public key?

Tags: certificate, digital-signature, public-key, pki

If I know well, many digital certificate can contain a single public key. But I didn't see a certificate containing more public key.

I would like to know if it is completely impossible to a certificate containing more public key.

Comment: There is only one private and one public key per certificate.  Having multiple public keys for a certificate does not make sense.

Comment: Assuming you are talking about an X.509 certificate, read [RFC 5280 Section 4](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5280#section-4) for a breakdown of its internals.

Comment: What exactly are you talking about when you say 'certificate'?  There are many files types that can contain multiple certificates.  IE a a pkcs12 can have a private key, and many certs building up a trust chain.

Answer (score 1):

You could conceivably stuff an extra key into a cert using a private extension but you would be the only one with any idea of what it means or what to do with it.